# Google API purchases.subscriptionsv2 method

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to get info about subscription purchases (in the backend).
We have a mobile app that sells some subscriptions plans.
Also we have backend/API for the mobile app.

What I'm trying to do is to get information about subscription payments (active subscriptions).

To get that info I need to fetch the following endpoint. I have created service account and unfortunately I can't get data. Probably there missing some roles attached to the service account.

Does anyone know which role is required to get access to this resource?

```json
{
    'code': 401, 
    'message': 'The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.', 
    'errors': [
                  {
                      'message': 'The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation.',
                      'domain': 'androidpublisher', 
                      'reason': 'permissionDenied'
                  }
              ]
}
```

Thanks